# Curl - Sending hundreds of requests but only four at a time - Programming

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, visual-c++, libcurl

How do you proceed to solve this problem? I've hundreds of requests to be sent to Curl but I can send only four at a time.

Thus, I need to make four requests using curl at the same time and processes their responses. However, once one of the curl pointer is available, I need to send another request.

This is because, the server can handle only four requests at a time but I've hundreds of requests to be sent to the server.

Following is the code, I got from curl site

```
    int main(void)
    {
      const int HANDLECOUNT = 4;
      CURL *handles[HANDLECOUNT];
      CURLM *multi_handle;

      int still_running = 0; /* keep number of running handles */ 
      int i;

      CURLMsg *msg; /* for picking up messages with the transfer status */ 
      int msgs_left; /* how many messages are left */ 

      /* Allocate one CURL handle per transfer */ 
      for(i = 0; i<HANDLECOUNT; i++)
        handles[i] = curl_easy_init();

      /* set the options (I left out a few, you'll get the point anyway) */ 
      curl_easy_setopt(handles[0], CURLOPT_URL, "website");
      curl_easy_setopt(handles[0], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XMLRequestToPost.c_str());
      curl_easy_setopt(handles[0], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(XMLRequestToPost.c_str())); 
      curl_easy_setopt(handles[1], CURLOPT_URL, "website");     
      curl_easy_setopt(handles[2], CURLOPT_URL, "website");    
      curl_easy_setopt(handles[3], CURLOPT_URL, "website");    

      /* set the request for other 3 handles too */
      /* init a multi stack */ 
      multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

      /* add the individual transfers */ 
      for(i = 0; i<HANDLECOUNT; i++)
        curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, handles[i]);

      /* we start some action by calling perform right away */ 
      curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);

      while(still_running) {
      }


     }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just figure out what has completed and start another transfer in that slot? https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html

Comment: Why can you only send 4 at a time? Curl's multimode can handle a lot more.

Comment: Shawn, that is a limitation of the server who is receiving the request. I can't send more than 4 at a time.

Comment: the `still_running` variable you get back from `curl_multi_perform()` tells you how many are ongoing, as soon as it goes below 4 you can remove that handle, set new options and add it again to get next transfer going...

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That is interesting. Will test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread-safe queue to put your requests into.

Start 4 threads, each one with its own CURL object.

Have each thread run a loop that:

- pulls the next request from the queue,
- sends it
- processes/dispatches the response as needed,
- and repeats

Until the queue is empty.